# Querying the cached response in WSO2 DSS/ESB

Tags: caching, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a Oracle database view containing details of around 8000 employees. I need to populate employee search suggestions from that view. I'm planning to use WSO2 DSS/ DSS+ESB to create a data service for that. Rather querying the view for each and every service call, i'm thinking of caching the whole view in DSS/ESB and query the cache for all the filter queries("like", "where" queries) until cache expires.

Is there any possibilities around ESB/DSS related to the above scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **cache** mediator with WSO2 ESB :

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <cache id="someCache" scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" timeout="10">
                <onCacheHit>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property name="debug" value="incache"/>
                    </log>
                    <header name='To' action="remove"/>
                    <send/> <!-- send back previous reponse, outSequence will not be executed -->
                </onCacheHit>
                <implementation type="memory" maxSize="1000"/>
            </cache>
            <send> <!-- Current request (hash) has not been found in the cache -->
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://myhost:8080/myapp/MyService"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <cache id="someCache" scope="per-host" collector="true"/> <!-- Add this response to the cache -->
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="debug" value="outseq"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Inside the inSequence, if current request exists in the cache, 'onCacheHit' mediation will be executed with previous response. Otherwise, the 'send' to the endpoint will be executed

Inside outSequence, you add the response to the cache

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ya this works for the queries without filtering(this is a feature in DSS as well), but in my case i have queries which includes lot of filtering(using 'like' / 'where'). So default caching(response caching) won't work. So what i'm trying to have is a data caching layer, which fetches data once a day from source and process all the queries in that layer without hitting the source more than once a day.

Comment: With my level of knowledge of WSO2 ESB, I can hardly imagine implementing such a data cache inside the ESB and I can't help you with DSS, sorry.